# Solve a simultaneous equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do we solve $|b-y|=b+y-2\;and\;|b+y|=b+2$? I have tried to square them and factorize them but got confused by *and* and *or* conditions.

Comment: @ Jasper Loy: No other condition.

Comment: The language seems ambiguous here. In one interpretation, $b$ is given and you are expected to solve the two equations separately for $y$. In another, you are expected to solve the system of two equations for two unknowns $b$ and $y$. Common naming conventions support the first interpretation, since $a$, $b$, $c$ etc. are often used for given parameters, while $x$, $y$, $z$ etc. are used for variable or unknown quantities. Maybe you can infer what is meant from context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$b+2=|b+y|$ which is real, so is $b$

$y+b-2=|b-y|$ which is real, so is $y+b-2$ and $y$

(1)If $b \ge y, b-y=b+y-2\implies y=1 \implies |b+1|=b+2$ and $b \ge y=1$

So, $b+1 >0\implies |b+1|=b+1=b+2$ which has no finite solution.

(2) If $b<y, y-b=b+y-2\implies b=1, y>b=1$

So, $|1+y|=3\implies y+1=3\implies y=2$

The only solution $b=1,y=2$.

Answer (score 3):

$2\min (b,y)=b+y-|b-y|=2$ so that $\min (b,y)=1$. This implies that $b$ and $y$ are both positive so that $b+y=b+2$. Hence $y=2$ and $b=1$.

Comment: what happens if $b+y\lt0$? You cannot replace $|b+y|$ with $b+y$ unless you know that $b+y\ge0$.

Comment: correct you are. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

We always have $b+y-|b-y|=2\min(b,y)$ and from the first of the equations given, this is $2$.  Therefore, we know that
$$
\min(b,y)=1
$$
Since we know that $\min(b,y)=1$, we know that $b+y>0$ and so $|b+y|=b+y$. Therefore, the second equation is $b+y=b+2$, which gives us
$$
y=2
$$
So the solution is $b=1$ and $y=2$.